# windows phone 7 picture metadata

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to read picture data such as date picture taken, filename, GPS location and other information that is stored inside the images that stored in the medialibrary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can find the GDI+ components you would need for this are **not** currently available on the phone (or Silverlight for that matter).  You can have a webservice provide this data to you or you can look into porting a desktop library, it seems some people [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/68464/394008.aspx) have had luck with that.

There is also a project called **ExifLib** that loads the metadata without the extra GDI+ overhead.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/exiflib.aspx

Comment: thanks. i was able to download then reference the exiflib.dll and then simply                 
JpegInfo info = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto, e.OriginalFileName);   

as shown in tim's project:
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/09/23/working-with-pictures-in-camera-tasks-in-windows-phone-7-orientation-rotation.aspx